# INT trap not working when using DEBUG trap

Tags: bash

The following code is the content of my .bashrc. That's all there is.
Why is the terminal not printing `sigint` when hitting <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>? It prints `pre`, so i assume that the `DEBUG` trap somehow takes precedence over the `INT` trap. Or is something else going on here?

```
trap sig_int INT;     

preexec(){
  trap '' DEBUG
  echo pre
  return 1
}

function sig_int(){
  echo sigint
}

postexec() {
  echo post
  trap preexec DEBUG
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=postexec
shopt -s extdebug
```

Comment: I tested it in a new script. After your code (I added `exit 0` after the `echo sigint`) I wrote `while :; do sleep 1; done`. Running this script and entering `^C` printed `sigint`. Do you have the same problem in a new script?

Comment: @Walter A: This is not for a script, it is the .bashrc and supposed to run on interactive commands.

Comment: It seems to work different from `.bashrc`, I try to get it isolated: save it in a different file, source that file and try ^C from the command line. No spectacular results.

Comment: I tried to find it for you, but https://serverfault.com/a/891394 did not help for me. Perhaps https://jichu4n.com/posts/debug-trap-and-prompt_command-in-bash/ helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the terminal not printing sigint when hitting <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>?

No, it prints `sigint` after `pre`. I add `set -x` at the head of the script in my `.bashrc`, it prints `pre` firstly:

```
$ ^C+++ preexec
+++ trap '' DEBUG
+++ echo pre
pre
+++ return 1
++ sig_int
++ echo sigint
sigint

+++ preexec
+++ trap '' DEBUG
+++ echo pre
pre
+++ return 1
++ postexec
++ echo post
post
++ trap preexec DEBUG
```

> It prints `pre`, so i assume that the debug trap somehow takes precedence over the int trap. Or is something else going on here?

Check [another question about DEBUG signal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385035/305204):

> If a sigspec is DEBUG, the command arg is executed before every simple command, for command, case command, select command, every arithmetic for command, and before the first command executes in a shell function ...

So every time hitting <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>(as a command), `preexec` triggered by `DEBUG` signal will be executed firstly to print `pre`. Then `SIG_INT` will be sent to run `sig_int` to print `sigint`.

Comment: I'm glad that it's working on your machine. I used set -x and have a similar output to yours, but everything after the first return 1 to postexec (not including) is missing here... Bash version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @alexanderremus  my bash version is GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). you can use `trap -p` to print your trap setup. May be your INT trap is not set to `sig_int`